# Random numbers once a time

Tags: java

i want to random numbers only at once. i searched to get this and learned there is shuffle function. it is ok but i wonder what is wrong here. this code doesn't work it generates same numbers.

```
public class panel {
    boolean[] generated = new boolean[5];
    int[] grid = new int[5];

    panel() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5 i++) {
            int x = generaterandom();
            generated[x] = true;
            grid[i] = x;
            System.out.println(grid[i]);

        }
    }

    public int generaterandom() {
        int r = random.nextInt(5);
        if (generated[r]) generaterandom();
        return r;
    }
}
```

Comment: if a number is generated i want to generate a new one. i dont want to generate same numbers.

Comment: so basically there is something wrong with collision of numbers. if the index already has a number you want to generate another number.

Comment: You need to put the numders 0-4 into a collection then shuffle it

Comment: but basically your recursion does not reassign the value of r, so it will always remain at the original value of r

Comment: calling `genereaterandom` recursively but **not** using its returned value does not help - and can easily end up in a never ending or very long call chain - There are better solutions on this site for generating random numbers without repetition, for example search: [`[java] random no repetition`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+random+no+repetition)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you recurse, you calculate a new r which is returned .ok.
But you don't use it within the caller.
So you always return the r of the very first step.
Try

```
if (generated[r]) r = generaterandom();
        return r;
```